# Trouble aligning list elements the way I want

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a list of post titles with their featured image above it. The last post title in the list is two lines, so it messes up the alignment of the list. Below is an image. I want the first three posts to move upwards to align with the last one.

[image]

The code:

```
<div class="classes-links">
  <?php 
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'class',
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
      'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
  ?>

  <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
      <ul><li><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></li>
          <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>
      </ul>
    </a>
  <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.classes-services .classes-div .classes-links {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px 250px 0 0;
}

.classes-services .classes-div .classes-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #113337;
}

.classes-services .classes-div .classes-links ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Why are you puttin different `ul` inline instead of create a unique `ul`? anyway, try to give `vertical-align: top` to the `ul` displayed inline-block and it should work.

Comment: Wow I could have sworn I tried this, worked!

Comment: @lecya, you should really put this information in an answer so MrDevRI can check it off as a solution... I know it may seem silly, but people should not have to search through the comments to find the right answer.  This would be helpful to beginners as not many people know that vertical-align works with inline items, and that you don't need a table.

Answer (score 1):

give `vertical-align: top` to the ul displayed inline-block and it should work

Comment: It's too bad the OP doesn't want to give you credit for your answer!!!  MrDevRI should upvote you, and accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score -1):

You could put them in a table and set valign:top; on the tr element. If you use percentage based width for the table and the td elements, it will flex fine if your application is responsive.

This will align the images to the top instead of middle aligning the text and image.

Comment: `vertical-align` works with inline elements as well, don't need to change the html

Comment: I thought you had to set the elements container to `display: table-cell` for that to work. No?

Comment: Tables should be used for tabular data only and NEVER for page layout.  Using divs or other elements and faking a table display with table, table-row and table-cell is fine because you can later change the CSS to alter the layout to be more responsive... like on a mobile device, for example.

Comment: Try building an HTML layout for email without using tables and have it render properly on all email clients. There is nothing inherently wrong with using tables for CONTENT layout - it is just ill advised to use tables to lay out an entire page (unless it's for HTML email purposes). Also, tables respond perfectly well when using percent based width for content - even on mobile.

Comment: Daniel was talking about faking table, table-row and table-cell display, not using `table`. Anyway `vertical-align` works for `inline`, `inline-block` and `td` elements

Comment: Huh, good to know. Did not know that vertical-align worked on inline elements. Thanks.

Comment: You can't build an email template to work in all email clients even **WITH** tables... so let's not compare apples to oranges.  And to respond to your comment about tables responding with percent based widths, you are correct.  However, try to move an entire column above or below another column with actual table tags... this is why faking tables with divs, or other elements, is a better choice... this way you can remove table-like properties, via css, and have content flow more appropriately in different viewing environments.  Thanks for the backup @lecya :)

Comment: You can so long as the client allows HTML - which most modern clients do. You just have to be very meticulous about your inline CSS and pay close attention to which clients recognize specific tags. By collapsing all borders on the tables and paying close attention to detail, I am able to get the markup to a point where rendering only reflects minute differences across clients.
CampaignMonitor has a good reference I often use when building out HTML eMails.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Way off topic at this point - sorry about that.

Comment: Not to worry... and I'm not trying to pick a fight either.  I have done email templates for over 9 years now, so I'm very familiar with what you are saying in regards to those... which is why I am not fighting your argument over using tables for email templates.  In fact, zurb.com has some really nice ones that work in all but Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013.  I was merely trying to discourage the use of tables (outside of email templates) for layout purposes as I think it's not necessary with today's CSS, and way more restrictive.

Comment: Outlook :( The bane of my existence. Outlook 07/10/13 is always the batch that gives me migraines because we use Outlook in house and everyone seems to be on a different version of it - yet as I am sure you know, none of the versions allow max-width or min-width, so making anything close to a  "responsive" template is a nightmare. Ugh...